# htaccess Redirect sub directories except index.php

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a htaccess file in www.mydomain.com/dir.

I want to redirect requests from www.mydomain.com/dir/* to www.mydomain.com/dir except www.mydomain.com/dir/index.php

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond DOCUMENT_ROOT/ !-f
RewriteRule ^/*$ index.php
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does 'from www.mydomain.com/dir/* to www.mydomain.com/dir' mean?

Comment: Requests to www.mydomain.com/dir/* should be redirected to www.mydomain.com/dir. I don't want sub directories of "dir" to be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dir/

RewriteRule (?!^index\.php$)^.+$ index.php [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

That works almost!

www.mydomain.com/dir/.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dir/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (?!^index\.php$)^.+$ index.php [L,NC]
```

But when I access any file or sub directory in *dir* I get 404. The index.php is located in *dir* and any request to file or sub directory in *dir* should be redirected to *dir/index.php*.